# HTML5 : <!DOCTYPE html> changes page style

Tags: css, html

When I use HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` this code the `<div>` with id previous have a 5.5 pixels in height more than the width (5.5 pixels in my screen it will change depending on window size but will always be different).

And when I remove when I remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` it has the same width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="previous" style="background-color: gray;width: 5%;border-radius: 100%;">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Circle_arrow_left_font_awesome.svg/240px-Circle_arrow_left_font_awesome.svg.png" alt="previous" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried reset browsers style (setting `margin` and `padding`, ... to 0) and tried setting `width` and `height` of `<html>` and `<body>` to 100% didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block` to your image's style. By default images are displayed inline, which means space below for descenders.

Comment: it does work but this part `space below for descenders` i didn't understand

Comment: Inline elements leave space below the baseline to allow for descenders, like on letters p and q. So as long as your image is displayed inline it will have that space beneath it. More information [here](https://mor10.com/removing-white-space-image-elements-inline-elements-descenders/)

Comment: put your answer and the link of the explanation to the duplicate question please